# Two Calls to NodeJS Server are Interfering with one another

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, web

Relatively new to Node.JS and have a simple server using the http.createServer listening on port 8081. It listens for Ajax calls from a simple webpage.  No issues getting the node to listen and respond to requests as expected.  The one problem I am running into though, is when I introduce a second request to the same node at the same time through another browser instance, or on another machine, the second request produces the results based on the first calls parameters.

When debugging the server I can see both requests coming in with the different parameters as expected, but it is as if the second request overrides the first one.  Coming from a .NET background I initially thought that I had global variables that were being shared between the calls - but I've eliminated all globals.

Is there something painfully obvious that I am missing in keeping two separate node calls completely unique?

Below is the code I am using,... (posted late)

```
var http = require("http"),
    url = require('url');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var Params = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
    var CallSettings = Defaults();
    CallSettings.Location = Params.Location;
    CallSettings.Threshold = Params.Threshold;
    CaptureDataFromHost(request, response, CallSettings);

}).listen(8081);

function CaptureDataFromHost(request, response, CallSettings) {
    try {
        for (var Page = 0; Page < Pages; Page++) {
            var http = require("http"),
                url = require('url');
            var RequestString = '';
            var request = require('request');
            request(RequestString, function(error, response2, body) {
                if (!error && response2.statusCode == 200) {
                    var ResponseAsObject = JSON.parse(body);
                    CallSettings.ResponseCount++;
                    for (var i = 0; i < ResponseAsObject.products.length; i++) {
                        // various local business logic here,...
                    }

                    // If it is the last page response, run aggregate data,...
                    if (CallSettings.ResponseCount == CallSettings.Pages) {
                        AggregateAllProductData(response, Location,
                            CallSettings);
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Added the code late!

Comment: no need to require http and url in every iteration of your loop, they are already defined in the outer scope

Comment: also, you are overwriting the request argument of your CaptureDataFromHost by requiring a request module, that won't work

Answer (score 0):

Require in loop ... ARGH!!

As @PatrickHund said : require the request module a second time is the obvious problem you were looking for.

Always require your modules at the beginning of your script! if this still doesnt work, I would also like to know what is Default() (l. 6)

Answer (score 0):

Just an update here.  Yes, the require in loop was a problem. But the issue that was creating the call interference was that the 'Defaults' declaration:

var CallSettings = Defaults();

should be var CallSettings = new Defaults();

By adding this, every single call had it's own unique definitive object.